# Google App Engine swf files paritally downloading

Tags: google-app-engine, flash

I'm just getting started with Google App Engine and I have a few questions.  Some of my swf files are halting their download after loading the first 10%.  This doesn't happen on a traditional web host, or when running the GAE app locally.  I'd like to verify that the file has uploaded properly, but I can't figure out how to view the files associated with an app once they've been uploaded to Google App Engine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to view files on the server. But you could download app files from the server:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_an_Application

Also I suggest to use Google Cloud Storage for such files, there you can upload/download/verify/etc from the browser (or command line), and it better suits for serving static files, especially large ones